# how to generate a list from a maps entries with a specific key

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to extract all entries from a map, which have a specific key, to a list?

F.e. I have a map with the following form:

```json
[
  {
    "temp": 12,
    "date": 01.07.2022,
  },
  {
    "temp": 23,
    "date": 02.07.2022,
  },
  {
    "temp": 17,
    "date": 03.07.2022,
  }
]
```

What I want is a list like this for the key "temp": `[12, 23, 17]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Iterator.map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method on the list:

```dart
final data = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {
    "temp": 12,
    "date": "01.07.2022",
  },
  {
    "temp": 23,
    "date": "02.07.2022",
  },
  {
    "temp": 17,
    "date": "03.07.2022",
  }
];

final temperatures = data.map((datum) => datum["temp"]).toList();

print(temperatures); // [12, 23, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `map` method on `List` which take a function taking an element of the original list (which will be a map). Extract the `temp` int from the map. For example:

```
    final result = list.map<int>((e) => e['temp'] as int).toList();
```